# moving average in pandas, issue with first and last rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I'm computing the moving average over a window of 5 periods on column of my dataframe. This is the code I wrote:

```
df['Volume_moving'] = df['Volume'].rolling(window = 5, center = True).mean()
```

this is the dataset with the new column created:

```
             Open    High    Low    Close   Volume    Adj Close Volume_moving
Date                            
2012-10-15  632.35  635.13  623.85  634.76  15446500    631.87  NaN
2012-10-16  635.37  650.30  631.00  649.79  19634700    646.84  NaN
2012-10-17  648.87  652.79  644.00  644.61  13894200    641.68  18514440.0
2012-10-18  639.59  642.06  630.00  632.64  17022300    629.76  19330360.0
2012-10-19  631.05  631.77  609.62  609.84  26574500    607.07  20454460.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... .... .... ....     ...... ..... ........ 
2013-01-08  529.21  531.89  521.25  525.31  16382400    525.31  18185340.0
2013-01-09  522.50  525.01  515.99  517.10  14557300    517.10  16443720.0
2013-01-10  528.55  528.72  515.52  523.51  21469500    523.51  18221260.0
2013-01-11  521.00  525.32  519.02  520.30  12518100    520.30  NaN
2013-01-14  502.68  507.50  498.51  501.75  26179000    501.75  NaN
```

The column 'Volume_moving' has the right values except for the first and last two rows where it is NaN, now For x=1 and x=2, I want that the moving average is calculated using three and four rows, respectively (same for the last two rows). How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share the sample data

Comment: Sorry, Just added!

Comment: simply use `min_periods=3` option in rolling function. This will solve your problem! [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: you can try without center hyper parameter that will mean first 4 rows will come as null .

Comment: That's not what I need, I need the center parameter.